как обработать исключение для каждого выражения pandas в python?
Создаю автоматизированное преобразование excel файла.
Преобразование выполняю примерно так:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
doc = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx')
df['Наименование'] = doc.loc[0, 'Наименование ПО']
df['Вид программы'] = 'ПО' 
df['Ответсвенный отдел'] = doc.loc[0, 'Отдел']
df['Тип проекта'] = 'Технологический'

В input.xlsx могут отсутствовать некоторые поля.
Вопрос: Как мне обработать исключения одним выражением для всех выражений(строк)?
Чтобы не писать try except для каждого выражения(строки)?
Т.е. если падает исключение KeyError, то пропустить.

Думал может использовать декоратор, но как-то не идет у меня (

EAFP против LBYL! Надо переименовывать только 4 заголовка?

Всего полей около 60-ти. Ещё я планировал делать лог. Например так: logging.Error(f'Поле {field} не найдено.') и  например logging.info(f'Значение {value} установлено.')

Т.е., Вы пытаетесь стандартизировать свои файлы. Логирование Вам точно не нужно (логи надо будет читать) - можно сразу глазками по файлам пробежаться и ручками исправить... А сколько таких файлов!?

Скрипт на вход будет принимать один файл, но в будущем будут и другие, за корректность которых я отвечать не могу. Поэтому, думаю как сделать так, чтобы пользователи могли понять, что не так и что нужно исправить. Ну и чтобы из-за одного несуществующего поля скрипт не падал.

Вообще ручками тут не поправить, т.к. в своём DataFrame создаю по 30 строк на каждую строку из входящего файла. Это нужно ещё и для интеграции через excel адаптер.

Во входящем файле около 200 строк

Вам всё-равно придётся модифицировать программу. Не проще ли тогда сделать как я вам в ответе написал - подготовить словари соответствия полей? Минимум кода, код управляется данными. Никакого повторения кода, если что-то меняется в программе, то меняется только в маленьком куске кода. Если меняются поля - опять же меняются только словари, код не нужно менять. И всё это при желании можно вынести в функцию, а словари обернуть в ещё один словарь, где будет ключ - название файла, а в значениях таблицы соответствия. Можно вообще в json файл это потом вынести и менять только этот json.

Если сами затрудняетесь реализовать, то найдите фрилансера. До недавнего момента Я отвечала на такие вопросы, но тут есть одна "Собака на сене" (Lope de Vega) - сейчас я не готова тратить время не получая компенсации. Успехов!

@CrazyElf Твой ответ действительно помог и теперь я занят внесением изменений в код. Но мне стало интересно, что если у тебя есть много однотипных выражений, которые я, например, не хочу вносить в цикл. Можно ещё например переопределить метод. Создать свой класс наследуясь от pandas к примеру.

У меня нет опыта в наследовании поэтому вот))

@DonPerez Ну, в Питоне вообще много чего можно сделать. Можно вообще какой-то свой язык написать, на котором написать конфигурацию, которая будет уже управлять копированием ваших датафреймов. Это если продолжать мои идеи. А насчёт классов да, можно написать класс, который будет собственно делать такое копирование. Наследование там не нужно, он просто будет пользоваться Pandas. А если вы хотите изменить поведение самой библиотеки Pandas, то это не так то просто сделать. Проще написать некий класс, который будет пользоваться Pandas и делать то, что вы хотите и то, что вы в него заложили.

@CrazyElf Я пробовал создать функции типа set_value(df, index, value) и get_value(df, index, column), но выходит как-то громоздко)

Ну, можно примерно так оптом такое обработать:
columns_fixed = {
    'Вид программы': 'ПО',
    'Тип проекта': 'Технологический',
}

columns_copy = {
    'Наименование': 'Наименование ПО',
    'Ответсвенный отдел': 'Отдел',
}

for k, v in columns_fixed.items():
    df[k] = v

for k, v in columns_copy.items():
    if v in doc.columns:
        df[k] = doc.loc[0, v]

Просто наполняете словари и запускаете код. Падать ничего не должно - наличие столбца в датафрейме предварительно проверяется.
Если нужно логирование или всё же ловля ошибок - всё это добавляется внутрь цикла один раз, копипасту делать не нужно будет. Но нужно будет подготовить словари соответствия полей.

Ответ подходит, спасибо!
